# How to encrypt all my data in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to use one of the encryption algorithms say DES encryption to store all the data in my Drupal database. Is there a way I can do that? Based on my understanding there needs to go some encrypt/decrypt functions in all database calls from the code?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://drupal.org/project/encrypt it might be worth a try.

> ***Encrypt***
>
> Encrypt is a Drupal module that provides an application programming
> interface (API) for performing two-way data encryption. It allows
> modules to encrypt data such that it can be decrypted using the same
> key that was used to encrypt the data. This is useful for storing
> sensitive information.
>
> There is no native way to do two-way encryption in Drupal. There is
> also not a very standard way of performing encryption in PHP without
> extensions. This module aims to make it easy for other modules to keep
> data secured in an extensible way that does not inherently require any
> other dependencies.

Comment: the encrypt module does not help me secure all my data.. it provides a two-way encryption API.. i'm sure this has to deal with drupal core..